# Electron Builder - multiple Windows target

Tags: windows, electron, executable, electron-builder

I am using Electron Builder to package my Electron application. For Windows, I want both 32 and 64 bit versions, as single executables. I have this in my `package.json`:

```json
"build": {
    "appId": "…",
    "win": {
        "target": [{
            "target": "portable",
            "arch": [
              "x64",
              "ia32"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "icon": "images/ … .ico"
    },
    "directories": {
        "output": "../electron-builder/${name}/${os}"
    }
}
```

I then run the following:

```bash
npx electron-builder
```

When it finishes, I get the following in the target directory:

```
win-ia32-unpacked
win-unpacked
something.exe
```

I was hoping to get a single executable for each version, but I only get the one executable. I’m not quite sure, but I presume that it’s a 64 bit version.

How do I get both 32 and 64 bit executables ?